# After button clicked, save to MySQL then display CSS highlight

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

I've got a Rating function that does as follows: Once a user clicks the +1 button, the rating goes up by 1, and saves to MySQL. What I'd like for it to do is once clicked, it changes
the background to a different color as shown below..

**( What I'd like for it to do is the "once clicked" ) at the current moment it just updates the number with the background being white)**

NOTE: I'm just asking for suggestions or some way to lead me in the right direction, thank you in advance.

Without being clicked:

[image]

Once clicked:

[image]

php/html form: to submit the +1

```
<div class="up vote" name="voteUp" id="<?php echo $post_iD;?>">
    <div class="wrapper">+<?php echo $VoteRate;?></div>
</div>
```

AJAX: to update the button

```
$(function()
{
    $(".vote").click(function()
    {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        var name = $(this).attr("name");
        var dataString = 'id='+ id ;
        var parent = $(this);

        if (name=='voteUp')
        {
            $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: "voting/up_vote.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html)
                {
                    parent.html(html);
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

up_vote.php: submit from the ajax

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 
if($_POST['id'])
{
    $sth = $db->prepare("SELECT add_iP FROM PostsRating WHERE post_iD_fk = :id AND add_iP = :ip");
    $sth->execute(array(':id' => $_POST['id'], ':ip' => $ip));

    if( $sth->fetchColumn() == 0)
    {
            $sth = $db->prepare("UPDATE posts set voteUp = voteUp+1 where post_iD = :id");
            $sth->execute(array(':id' => $_POST['id']));

            $sth = $db->prepare("INSERT into PostsRating (post_iD_fk, add_iP) VALUES (:id, :ip)");
            $sth->execute(array(':id' => $_POST['id'], ':ip' => $ip));
    } else  {
            $sth = $db->prepare("UPDATE posts set voteUp = voteUp-1 where post_iD = :id");
            $sth->execute(array(':id' => $_POST['id']));

            $sth = $db->prepare("DELETE FROM PostsRating WHERE post_iD_fk = :id AND add_iP = :ip");
            $sth->execute(array(':id' => $_POST['id'], ':ip' => $ip));
    }

    $sth = $db->prepare("SELECT voteUp FROM posts WHERE post_iD = :id");
    $sth->execute(array(':id' => $_POST['id']));

    $row = $sth->fetch();   

    echo $row['voteUp'];
}
```

Comment: You *might* want to be careful setting the ID of that element to a numerical value. Not sure of the implications, but you're not using `id` for what it's meant to be used as. Instead, you could use `data-id="123"` for such case as jQuery can read data values.  With that said, what's your question?

Comment: @RobW, thank you for answering I will take a loot into that. I updated the post with a bold text with the question.

Comment: added answer which should help. You just need to add a new css class and then apply the class as necessary. There's probably other ways to do this, but this is the most basic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your success callback, why not just set a class to the `parent` and then update the `.wrapper`?

```
success: function(html)
{
    parent.addClass("blue");
    parent.find(".wrapper").html("+ " + html);
}
```

When the user refreshes the page and you want to continue to show the blue, you would simply:

```
<?php
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 
$sth = $db->prepare("SELECT add_iP FROM PostsRating WHERE post_iD_fk = :id AND add_iP = :ip");
$sth->execute(array(':id' => $post_iD, ':ip' => $ip));
$class = ($sth->fetchColumn()) ? " blue" : "";
?>
<div class="up vote<?php echo $class; ?>" name="voteUp" id="<?php echo $post_iD;?>">
    <div class="wrapper">+<?php echo $VoteRate;?></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're correct for 50%, the only issue is that once the page is refreshed the blue class disappears and the white background returns. That was mainly my question, though I liked this approach, just how do I save the blueclass once clicked as well.

Comment: On the page refresh, you would need to detect a user vote before rendering the initial button.

Comment: added the other 50% to my answer.

Comment: What if the user clicks the button again and the background must be removed. :/

Comment: Then instead of `addClass` use `toggleClass`

Comment: Thank you, you have cleared up so much for me, just one thing that I don't understand. How will that php query save that the user has clicked the button, and if he has then the button stays blue, just last thing to clear up if possible and wouldn't it be better if I saved that he clicked on MySQL?

Comment: What? You're already using that query I used but in a different location. It just checks if his ID and POST exist; if it does, then he's +1'd it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can not have a class name with a space in it - it will be interpreted as two classes, *up* and *vote*.

Within the php you can echo something along the lines of (be sure to set dataType to json)

```
echo(json_encode(array("success"=>true)));
exit();
```

After which the jquery can handle the response:

```
function(result) {
    var result_string = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
    if(result_string.success) {
        $(this).children(".wrapper").css("background-color", "blue")
    }
}
```

Comment: I may be wrong, but it seemed that the OP wanted it to be interpreted as a single class

Answer (score 0):

You can change the success function to add the color with .css("background-color","blue") or if you want to have it always blue if the vote_counter is higher than you can add this to the top of your code:

```
if (parseInt($("#"+id).children(".wrapper").text()) >= 1) {
 $("#"+id).children(".wrapper").css("background-color","blue");
}
```